# Radix sort function in R

Tags: performance, r, radix-sort

I know that `sort` in R uses radix sort, and I played around in implementing it (mainly to be sure I understood the algorithm properly). However, my implementation is an order of magnitude slower than the native implementation in R.

I'm curious: **is there a way to implement radix sort in R so that it wouldn't be so slow?**

My code:

```
get_digit <- function(x, d) {
    # digits from the right
    # i.e.: first digit is the ones, second is the tens, etc.
    (x %% 10^d) %/% (10^(d-1))
}

radix_sort <- function(x) {
    # k is maximum number of digits
    k <- max(nchar(x))
    for(i in 1:k) {
        x_digit_i <- get_digit(x, i)
        # split numbers based on their i digit
        x_by_bucket <- split(x, x_digit_i)
        # recombine the vectors, now sorted to the i'th digit
        x <- unlist(x_by_bucket, use.names = FALSE)
    }
    # since each iteration is a stable sort, the final result
    # is a sorted array, yay!
    x
}
```

Checking the running time:

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> x <- sample(100)
> microbenchmark(radix_sort(x), sort(x))
Unit: microseconds
          expr     min      lq      mean   median      uq     max neval cld
 radix_sort(x) 459.378 465.895 485.58322 480.4835 496.779 649.956   100   b
       sort(x)  27.314  29.487  33.05064  31.9710  33.212  73.563   100  a 
> x <- sample(10000)
> microbenchmark(radix_sort(x), sort(x))
Unit: microseconds
          expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq       max
 radix_sort(x) 44317.123 44777.8965 46062.3446 45204.3715 45714.807 63838.148
       sort(x)   158.609   165.7485   198.3083   186.6995   206.099   750.832
```

Comment: Welcome, currently your title makes your question sound off-topic and so is likely the cause of your downvote. This is as asking us to write algorithms for you is off-topic. I'd recommend that you reword it like the body of your question.

Comment: I don't know what kind of answer you expect. I already told you why I believe it impossible to come close to R's implementation which is in compiled code. If you really want something fast, you can't implement it in pure R. That's why we have Rcpp.

Comment: I agree with Roland. Maybe it helps to understand what you have here is a for loop with a **side-effect** (`x` is modified) which is what typically cannot be *vectorized* (made faster via a replacement to one or more fast, compiled functions). So you're stuck with a `for` loop, for which R is infamous. Hence no alternative other than moving to a compiled language (Rcpp, fortran, etc.) if you need speeds.

Comment: Note that you can do `x <- x[order(x_digit_i)]` rather than the `unlist(split())` but beyond that, probably not much you can do within R.

Comment: @flodel, using order is indeed faster, but that uses the sorting algorithm built within R (so it's a bit of cheating :) )

Comment: "Along the way, you’ll learn about some common myths, such as that you need to call gc() to free up memory, or that for loops are always slow."
from: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#memory

For loops are slow because of object copying, and I'm trying to understand what in my code can be done to minimize it...

Comment: I've told you before and I'll say it again. Profile your code! Hadley covers how to do that as well in his book. I bet you'll see that most of the time is spent in the `split` calls, probably followed by `unlist`. If you want to speed this up, you need to avoid these.

Comment: Then here is another idea to avoid `split`: start with `z <- outer(x_digit_i, 0:9, "==")`. Then you you can do `x <- x[row(z)[z]]`. Or slightly faster, `x <- x[1L + (which(z) - 1L) %% length(x)]`

Comment: And another small improvement: `%%`, `%/%`, and `==` are faster with integers, so use `(x %% as.integer(10^d)) %/% as.integer(10^(d-1))` inside `get_digit`. It might also make the code more robust to floating point error issues when using `==` like I suggested.

Comment: @flodel great tips, just what I was looking for - thanks! (maybe add it as an answer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting these comments into an answer...

As pointed out, it will be a tall order to beat or even approach the computation times of the native `sort` function, as it is compiled from C. Often with R, the trick to make your code faster consists in composing with some of these fast compiled building blocks that are native functions. In particular, we would look to substitute `for` loops like the one you have with vectorized functions. Unfortunately, your use of a `for` loop here is particular in the sense that each iteration has a side-effect to the `x` vector. This means that the order of the operations is important and we cannot run the loop iterations independently in parallel or via vectorized functions.

If we cannot get rid of the `for` loop, we are left trying to optimize the code within the body of the loop. Let's start with a profile of your code:

```
x <- sample(10000)
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())
for (i in 1:10) z <- radix_sort(x)
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tmp)$by.total
#                         total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
# "radix_sort"                  8.26     99.76      0.72     8.70
# "split"                       7.34     88.65      0.06     0.72
# "split.default"               7.28     87.92      0.54     6.52
# "as.factor"                   6.74     81.40      0.08     0.97
# "factor"                      6.64     80.19      1.72    20.77
# "as.character"                4.34     52.42      4.34    52.42
# "unique"                      0.42      5.07      0.04     0.48
# "unique.default"              0.38      4.59      0.38     4.59
# "%%"                          0.14      1.69      0.14     1.69
# "get_digit"                   0.14      1.69      0.00     0.00
# "sort.list"                   0.12      1.45      0.02     0.24
# "order"                       0.08      0.97      0.06     0.72
# "unlist"                      0.06      0.72      0.06     0.72
# [...]
```

We see that the main culprit here is the use of `split`. Another surprise here is the use of `order` (it seems to be applied when figuring out the levels of `x_digit_i`) which you could consider like cheating given your objective.

So what alternative do we have to your use of `split`/`unsplit`? Essentially, you have a vector `x` that you want to reorder based on a vector of digits `x_digit_i`. One way is to use `outer` to create a matrix of `TRUE`/`FALSE` where each column locates a different digit (for a total of ten columns):

```
z <- outer(x_digit_i, 0:9, "==")
```

Then, you want to turn this matrix into a vector of indices, such that the first few indices will locate the zeroes, then the ones, etc (the equivalent of `idx <- order(x_digit_i)`. You can do so by doing:

```
idx <- row(z)[z]
```

or (harder to understand but a bit faster)

```
idx <- 1L + (which(z) - 1L) %% length(x)
```

Finally, you just have to do:

```
x <- x[idx]
```

Also note that since you are dealing with integers, your code might be a little faster (and more robust by avoiding floating point errors) if you make sure to use integers everywhere possible. In particular, your `get_digit` function could be rewritten as follows:

```
get_digit <- function(x, d) (x %% as.integer(10^d)) %/% as.integer(10^(d-1))
```

The benchmarks below show decent progress (where my suggestions are implemented under the name `sort_radix2`) bridging the gap with the native `sort`. I hope it helps!

```
x <- sample(100)
microbenchmark(radix_sort(x), radix_sort2(x), sort(x))
# Unit: microseconds
#            expr     min       lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
#   radix_sort(x) 964.692 972.3675 1025.35180 984.3775 1012.178 2233.397   100
#  radix_sort2(x) 250.642 256.5720  282.58952 261.2910  282.449 1266.061   100
#         sort(x)  82.270  86.1605   92.22669  88.0230   90.943  223.249   100

x <- sample(10000)
microbenchmark(radix_sort(x), radix_sort2(x), sort(x))
# Unit: microseconds
#            expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#   radix_sort(x) 71939.706 76147.1715 80028.7541 78389.8140 81512.4140 144632.484   100
#  radix_sort2(x) 24218.810 27613.3190 34841.8724 29477.7115 31772.9415 143283.337   100
#         sort(x)   411.691   454.4015   563.4825   492.6165   558.0925   3412.719   100
```